# gulp gulp-watch don't work

Tags: gulp, gulp-watch

I try following code.

```
  var gulp = require("gulp");
  var ps = require('child_process').exec;
  var watch = require('gulp-watch');

  gulp.task('exec_file', function() {
    var command = "/mnt/c/pg/expect/folder_sync";
    ps(command , function (err, stdout, stderr) {
      console.log(stdout);
    });
  });

  gulp.task("watch", function() {
    var targets = [
      './**'
    ];
    return watch(targets, ['exec_file']);
  });
```

However the code make a error.

What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside of the watch, you have to inform Gulp which task to start.

Replace the following line:

`return watch(targets, ['exec_file']);`

with this:

`watch(targets, function(){
  gulp.start('exec_file');
})`

or with this:

`watch(targets).on('change', function(){ gulp.start('exec_file')});`

P.S I'm not sure if you have to return anything.

Comment: anytime, no problem:)